# Filtering based on string comparison

Tags: bash, awk, cygwin

I have a file with multiple columns. I am trying to filter out records that have
identical values in the first two fields. Both the fields hold text values. This
is the command I am using:

```
cat input_file | awk -F'\t' '{if($1==$2) print $1 $2}'
```

When I run this command I get only those rows where the values in the fields are
numeric. The file contains several rows which have identical values in the two
fields which are not numeric. How do I force awk to do string comparison?

Also, is there any other way I can accomplish this? (I am new to Unix environment
and do not know too many tricks... would appreciate advice)

Comment: awk can read files itself. http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html

Comment: awk shouldn't care about string/number when comparing with `==`. When I try to run your command it works for me (with strings as well as numbers). Are you sure the lines are tab separated on the lines with strings. Maybe you can do: `hexdump -C your-file`. 0x09 == tab and 0x20 == space.

Comment: Thanks! the problem was with the separator. THe actual separator is not tab, but a long char sequence (had changed it to tab here to avoid confusion)..apparently the sequence had a trailing space which I had missed out.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to filter out all the rows where the first two columns are the same just do `awk '$1!=$2' file` as `awk` uses whitespace as the default field separator and it's default action is print.

```
$ cat file
1       1        col3   line1
two     two      col3   line2
three   3        col3   line3           
four4   four4    col3   line4

$ awk '$1!=$2' file
three   3        col3   line3           

$ awk '$1==$2' file
1       1        col3   line1
two     two      col3   line2
four4   four4    col3   line4
```

The field *type* is irrelevant and the use of `cat` isn't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Pure Bash

```sh
while read x y
do
  [ $x = $y ] && echo $x $y
done < input_file
```

Comment: This fails to print the other fields on the line. It's not hard to fix; change `x y` to `x y z` etc.

Comment: It also fails for various contents of "input_file". Just don't do this - use awk.

Answer (score 0):

You are actually doing it correct except that you have added `-F'\t'` which is creating problem for you.
In awk  The default value of the field separator FS is a string containing a single space, " ".

so you need to remove that `-F'\t'`.

for eg see below:

```
> cat temp
1       1 random text
some some random text
some more random text


> nawk '{if($1==$2){print}}' temp
1       1 random text
some some random text

> nawk -F'\t' '{if($1==$2){print}}' temp
>
```

I am not yet sure about why the second command didnt work. but yes the thing is you need to remove that `-F`

Answer (score 0):

I am taking the example made by sudo_O

```
[sgeorge@sgeorge-ld ~]$ cat s
1       1        col3   line1
two     two      col3   line2
three   3        col3   line3           
four4   four4    col3   line4
[sgeorge@sgeorge-ld ~]$ cat s | perl -lane '$F[0] == $F[1] && print'
1       1        col3   line1
two     two      col3   line2
four4   four4    col3   line4
```